# Pause HTML5 video player on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

i wanted to pause my video after clicking on the video.

While using the commands in the console everything works as it should. But if i use jQuery it does not work. Anyone know why?

```
       $("#video").click(function() {
            if(!$("#video").get(0).paused) {
                console.log("playing");
                showPlayBtn();
                $("#video").get(0).pause();
            } else {
                console.log("paused");
            }
        });
```

Html:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto">
    <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the Videoplayer
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.pause()` is a native VideoElement's method and not jQuery's method, you need a reference to it. But using: `$("#video").get(0)` to reference the video object inside handler function isn't necesarry, instead of that you can use just **this** which reference the same object.

You can check it:

```
$("#video").click(function() {
    console.log($("#video").get(0)==this);  //true 
}
```

I've checked your code in 2 different browsers and it does work. But perhaps you tried to call **$("#video")**, before it's actually loaded.
to fix that - add it after loading, for example like this:

```
$(function(){
    //inside here -> means after loading. So video element already exist
    $("#video").click(function() {
        if(!this.paused) {  //if this video element is NOT paused
            console.log("playing");
            showPlayBtn();  //some function of yours
            this.pause();  //pause this video element
        } else {
            console.log("paused");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mistake in your code missing a selector inside the `if` check:

```
    $("#video").click(function() {
        if(!$(this).get(0).paused) {
            console.log("playing");
            showPlayBtn();
            $(this).get(0).pause();
        } else {
            console.log("paused");
        }
    });
```

Or to be somewhat more efficient:

```
    $("#video").click(function() {
        var video = $(this).get(0);
        if(!video.paused) {
            console.log("playing");
            showPlayBtn();
            video.pause();
        } else {
            console.log("paused");
        }
    });
```

Here are my jQuery play/pause wrappers for html5 - things are wrapped in try/catch for when it isn't supported:

```
/**
 * Play an audio or video element
 * @method play
 * @for jQuery
 * @chainable
 * @return {jQuerySelector}
 */
$fn.play = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        try {
            this.play();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Pause an audio or video element
 * @method pause
 * @for jQuery
 * @chainable
 * @return {jQuerySelector}
 */
$fn.pause = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        try {
            this.pause();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Comment: Oh sorry - in the if check you forgot to put anything in the selector - and using `$(this)` rather than `$("#video")` again is simply quicker :-) - edited to add this

Comment: just messed up the code for stackoverflow. in my code i got the selector in the if section. but your code does not work either...

Comment: Just added my play/pause wrappers for jQuery - they're in a large project I'm working on... And just had an idea - some video elements automatically pause on click to start with - so is it possible that it's being paused by the system, but this code is actually un-pausing it instead? Try putting it in an `.on("mousedown", ...)` instead, and put a `return false` on the end to cancel the event?